# I-net Clear Report caching old data

Tags: java, crystal-reports

I am generating I-net report. After startup my app, the first report contains new data that I want, but when I try to generate a new report with new data - exported report (pdf) contains the same data as the first one.
The data is stored in Oracle DB table (Global Temporary Table).

```
Engine engine = new Engine(InetExportFormat.EXPORT_PDF);
engine.setReportFile(reportUrl);
engine.setConnection(connection);
engine.execute()

//receiving the pdf report from engine
fos = new FileOutputStream(pdfFile);
bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
for (int i = 1; i <= engine.getPageCount(); i++) {
    bos.write(engine.getPageData(i));
    bos.flush();
}
```

The *connection* and *pdfFile* for each "generate phase" are new. I tested it - each time the data in the tables is new - it is impossible to get old data from DB. So it should be cached, or something like that.

I am closing all opened connections.

The report file is each time new - some colors are changing randomly, so I can spot the differences.

Any Ideas why I got this behavior?

**#EDIT**
In addiction - first report always generate longer than others:

First = 500ms

Second and more = 50ms.

Comment: Is it really related to Crystal Reports?

Comment: I really do not know. Maybe CR sometimes caching some data, so somebody will tell me that. I read docs, didn't found anything.